# S combinator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinators, s-combinator

Can an analog of the [**S** combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) be expressed in Haskell using only standard functions (without defining it by equation) and without using lambda (anonymous function)?  I expect it to by of type `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.

For example, an analog of the **K** combinator is just `const`.

In fact i am trying to express the function `\f x -> f x x` using standard functions, but cannot think of any standard non-linear function to start with (that is a function that uses its argument more than once).

Comment: `\f x -> f x x` is `join` in the function monad.

Comment: I [blogged](http://brandon.si/code/do-applicative-functors-generalize-the-s-k-combinators/) about a link I noticed between the SK combinator calculus and applicative functors, and got some interesting comments from readers you might want to check out. See also more interesting comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7403708/176841)

Comment: what is a standard function?

Comment: @duplode i wonder if that counts as defining it by equation

Comment: @SassaNF, i meant anything fairly standard, like `(.)`, `($)`, possibly `flip` :).

Comment: But `\f x -> f x x` is not the **S** combinator. The **S** combinator is `\f g x -> f x (g x)`, which is a free theorem for its type.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: i know that it is not the **S** combinator. What is a *free theorem*?

Comment: @Alexey The short version is that there is a similarity between types and theorems called the Curry-Howard Correspondence. This means that finding a value of a given type is equivalent to finding a proof of the equivalent theorem. A free theorem is one for which a proof can be generated mechanically. In this case, given the type you mentioned, a value of that type (the function I mentioned) can be generated mechanically, thus "proving" the "theorem" for "free". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421085/good-introduction-to-free-theorems.

Comment: In other words, `\f g x -> f x (g x)` is an existence proof that the type `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` is inhabited. This function can be generated mechanically, i.e. "for free", in a way that is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217931/how-does-djinn-work. And, in fact, if you wanted to find a function `(<*>)` to use for for `((->) r`, you could just ask Djinn to do the proof for you.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into the Philip Wadler's paper.

Comment: @Alexey Actually, what I'm referring to isn't really "free theorems", which is the generation of *theorems* for free. This is the generation of *proofs* "for free" (through an automatic decision procedure that makes use of the CH Correspondence). Sorry for the confusion. The Wadler paper is still fascinating though.

Comment: See also [The Monad Reader Issue 17](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/issue17.pdf): The Reader Monad and Abstraction
Elimination.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`s = (<*>)` for the `((->) r)` [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) instance.

Comment: Sorry, what is `((->) r)`?

Comment: @Alexey It is all types `r ->`. Unfortunately, you can't do a section with a type operator in the same way you can with a normal operator. So, though you can do something like `(10*)`, this isn't valid Haskell `(r ->)`. Luckily, we do have a syntax that gives us an equivalent result: `((->) r)`. Note, however, that we cannot do the same with the second argument. This is actually intentionally forbidden (I think it makes type inference impossible in some cases), which is *why* we can't have type operator sections.

Comment: @Alexey So, if we have a type synonym `type Function a b = a -> b`, then `((->) r)` is equivalent to `Function r`.

Comment: So, `r` was just a type variable?

Comment: Impossibility to have something like `(-> Int)`, is it because Haskell does not allow contravariant functors, by any chance?

Comment: @Alexey: Yeah, `r` is a type variable. Actually, Haskell does have (or can have) contravariant functors (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant). The reason it doesn't allow something like `(-> Int)` is that if it allowed you to rearrange type arguments however you want through partial type application, you would essentially have a full lambda calculus at a type level. This would make type inference impossible.

Answer (score 22):

Although it doesn't look like it at first, [`ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) is the S combinator (and [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) is the combinator you're really after).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I think i will accept the other answer however because of the title of my question and since `Applicative` seems to be more general than `Monad`.

Comment: In fact, maybe `Monad` being more restrictive than `Applicative`, your answer is actually *better*.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used `(=<<), (>>=)`.

And they are included in Prelude

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where  
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it's only understandable when writing out types out as follows:

The [Wiki notation of the S combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) is

```
Sxyz = xz(yz)
```

Think of `x` as a function of two arguments, and `y` as one with one arguments, and `z` as a value. The value `z` is passed into `y`; that result together with `z` is passed into `x`.

The definition of [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) is

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

where f here is the Function functor [`((->) r)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Functor), which is just the prefix notation for the usual function type notation `r -> ..`
So just expanding the type results (hiding some `->` arrows for simplicity) in

```
 (<*>) :: f (a -> b)  ->  f a  ->  f b
          f (a -> b)      f a      f b
         r->(a -> b)     r->a     r->b
         r-> a -> b      r->a     r->b
         ^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^     ^
         x (2args)       y (1arg) z (value)
```

As in the S combinator, the value `z` (corresponds to `r`) is passed to `y`
(corresponds to `r -> a`); that result (corresponds to `a`) is passed together with `z` into `x` (corresponds to `r -> a -> b`) as the first argument. The final result corresponds to `b`.