# Can I verify whether a given function type signature has a potential implementation?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, hindley-milner

In case of explicit type annotations Haskell checks whether the inferred type is at least as polymorphic as its signature, or in other words, whether the inferred type is a subtype of the explicit one. Hence, the following functions are ill-typed:

```
foo :: a -> b
foo x = x

bar :: (a -> b) -> a -> c
bar f x = f x
```

In my scenario, however, I only have a function signature and need to verify, whether it is "inhabited" by a potential implementation - hopefully, this explanation makes sense at all!

Due to the parametricity property I'd assume that for both `foo` and `bar` there don't exist an implementation and consequently, both should be rejected. But I don't know how to conclude this programmatically.

Goal is to sort out all or at least a subset of invalid type signatures like ones above. I am grateful for every hint.

Comment: You may find `djinn-lib` and/or `djinn-ghc` somewhat helpful. See also `djinn`. See also http://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/ and note that lambdabot known how to use djinn as well.

Comment: Cf. also [*Given a Haskell type signature, is it possible to generate the code automatically?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10205793/2751851) and [*How does Djinn work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10217931/2751851)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Goal is to sort out all or at least a subset of invalid type signatures like ones above. I am grateful for every hint.

You might want to have a look at the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Basically, types in functional programs correspond to logical formulas.
Just replace `->` with implication, `(,)` with conjunction (AND), and `Either` with disjunction (OR). Inhabited types are exactly those having a corresponding formula which is a tautology in intuitionistic logic.

There are algorithms which can decide provability in intuitionistic logic (e.g. exploiting cut-elimination in Gentzen's sequents), but the problem is PSPACE-complete, so in general we can't work with very large types. For medium-sized types, though, the cut-elimination algorithm works fine.

If you only want a subset of not-inhabited types, you can restrict to those having a corresponding formula which is NOT a tautology in classical logic. This is correct, since intuitionistic tautologies are also classical ones. Checking whether a formula `P` is not a classical tautology can be done by asking whether `not P` is a satisfiable formula. So, the problem is in NP. Not much, but better than PSPACE-complete.

For instance, both the above-mentioned types

```
a -> b
(a -> b) -> a -> c
```

are clearly NOT tautologies! Hence they are not inhabited.

Finally, note that in Haskell `undefined :: T` and `let x = x in x :: T` for any type `T`, so technically every type is inhabited. Once one restricts to *terminating* programs which are free from runtime errors, we get a more meaningful notion of "inhabited", which is the one addressed by the Curry-Howard correspondence.

Comment: "There are algorithms which can decide provability in intuitionistic logic" Can you provide a reference? Keen to read about how this works; my gut tells me that provability seems like the sort of thing that might be undecidable, so will probably be fertile learning ground for me :)

Comment: I was seeking for a quick algorithmic solution and found a whole special field to study. I think to check if something is not a classical tautology is good enough for the time being. Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Above I am implicitly referring to simple types / propositional intuitionistic logic, where it is decidable. Once you start adding e.g. rank-2 polymorphism, GADTs, etc. things are no longer decidable, I believe. Anyway, for simple types you can take the Gentzen's LJ inference rules (without CUT) and do a proof search bottom-up, trying all the possible rules non-deterministically. Conveniently, going bottom-up, LJ rules only involve subformulas of the goal formula, which are finite, so we either find a proof, or we visit the same state again (allowing us to prune the search)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You can try to play with the rules in this [cool online demo](http://logitext.mit.edu/Intuitionistic/main). At every step in the bottom-up search, we only have a finite number of choices, and the search space is finite because of the subformula property. So, we either find a proof or revisit a previous state (so we can detect we are running in circles and prune the search branch).

Comment: @chi I checked if `fix` for strictly evaluated languages `((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b` is not a tautology for `a == True` and `b == False` and the result is positive, because the implication `((a -> b) -> a -> b)` yields `True` (considering `->` is right associative) and `a -> b` yields `False` and `True -> False` yields `False` and this means `fix` is not a tautology. Is there a mistake in my reasoning, because `fix` is of course inhabited?

Comment: @ftor `fix` (and anything that involves general recursion) is disallowed, since otherwise `fix id :: T` for any `T`, and all types are inhabited, which is not interesting. Basically, the Curry-Howard correspondence holds in the language without recursion. (some form of recursion could be allowed, e.g. primitive recursion)

Answer (score 7):

[Here's a recent implementation of that as a GHC plugin](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-justdoit) that unfortunately requires GHC HEAD currently.

---

It consists of a type class with a single method

```
class JustDoIt a where
  justDoIt :: a
```

Such that `justDoIt` typechecks whenever the plugin can find an inhabitant of its inferred type.

```
foo :: (r -> Either e a) -> (a -> (r -> Either e b)) -> (r -> Either e (a,b))
foo = justDoIt
```

For more information, read Joachim Breitner's [blogpost](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/735-The_magic_%E2%80%9CJust_do_it%E2%80%9D_type_class), which also mentions a few other options: [djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn) (already in other comments here), [exference](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exference), [curryhoward](https://github.com/Chymyst/curryhoward) for Scala, [hezarfen](https://github.com/joom/hezarfen) for Idris.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't really a self-contained answer to the question. Could you summarize some of the important points of the link? In the case of link-rot, there won't be anything helpful for future readers here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a link to the package itself on Hackage, and a short description of what it does.